# RazorEngine 3.4 throws System.ArgumentException: with cached @Layout and different Models

Tags: c#, unit-testing, razorengine

I have a problem with RazorEngine 3.4 caching. I have a few email templates with the same `@Layout` but different `Models` for each template. It works fine until I try to use the Cache I read that not use cache: `"will result in both dreadful performances and memory leaks"` [from here](http://mehdi.me/generating-html-emails-with-razorengine-part-03-caching-vs-integration-namespace-config/).

So I turned it on. It was simple but lead to a problem: the `_Layout.cshtml` is also cached with the first model type, when I try to parse an another template with a different Model it will throw an exception: `"System.ArgumentException: Object of type '....model1...' cannot be converted to type '...model2...'."`

I wrote 2 unit tests into `"IsolatedTemplateServiceTestFixture.cs"` to show the problem. The first one passes, but the second one fails because the `TemplateService.SetModelExplicit()` function wants to set the template.Model property with a different `Model` type for the `Layout`.

```
private Mock<ITemplateResolver> _templateResolver;

    [Test]
    public void IsolatedTemplateService_CanParseTemplateWithLayout_WithOneSerializableModels_UseCache()
    {
        _templateResolver = new Mock<ITemplateResolver>();
        var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration()
        {
            Resolver = _templateResolver.Object
        };

        using (var service = new TemplateService(config))
        {
            _templateResolver.Setup(i => i.Resolve("test")).Returns("<html>@RenderBody()</html>");

            const string template = @"@{Layout=""test"";}<h1>Hello @Model.Item1</h1>";
            const string expected = "<html><h1>Hello World</h1></html>";

            var model = new Tuple<string>("World");
            string result = service.Parse(template, model, null, "C1");
            string result2 = service.Parse(template, model, null, "C1");

            Assert.That(result == expected, "Result does not match expected: " + result);
            Assert.That(result2 == expected, "Result does not match expected: " + result2);
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void IsolatedTemplateService_CanParseTemplateWithLayout_WithDifferentSerializableModels_UseCache()
    {
        _templateResolver = new Mock<ITemplateResolver>();
        var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration()
        {
            Resolver = _templateResolver.Object
        };

        using (var service = new TemplateService(config))
        {
            _templateResolver.Setup(i => i.Resolve("test")).Returns("<html>@RenderBody()</html>");

            const string template = @"@{Layout=""test"";}<h1>Hello @Model.Item1</h1>";
            const string expected = "<html><h1>Hello World</h1></html>";

            var model = new Tuple<string>("World");
            string result = service.Parse(template, model, null, "C1");
            string result2 = service.Parse(template, model, null, "C1");

            const string template2 = @"@{Layout=""test"";}<h1>Hello2 @Model.Item1</h1>";
            const string expected2 = "<html><h1>Hello2 123</h1></html>";
            var model2 = new Tuple<int>(123);

            string result3 = service.Parse(template2, model2, null, "C2");

            Assert.That(result == expected, "Result does not match expected: " + result);
            Assert.That(result2 == expected, "Result does not match expected: " + result2);

            Assert.That(result3 == expected2, "Result does not match expected: " + result3);
        }
    }
```

My question is: anybody has the same problem? What would a "nice" way to workaround it until it will be fixed (if at all it happens)?

**Update:**

With the latest version (currently is v.3.10) both tests passed. So the problem was fixed.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  A link is nice, but simply hoping that for everyone to answer the question to link to another website means that when that link is gone, this question will be useless.

Comment: Probably not worth trying to fight this. Just make a bunch of views, one for each model.

Comment: But using one "big" Model with lots of properties for 15 templates is not cool. An another developer has no idea which one has to set for a specific template. I reported this issue, but no answer yet.
May be I will create a pull request and fix it myself...

Comment: Note that now "just works" in the latest RazorEngine versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is in RazorEngine, the layout has a fixed type, even if you don't declare a model in it. The first time the layout gets compiled by compiling a template, the template's model type becomes the layout's type as well. As you noticed, that will clash when you try to compile another template with a different type.

You can work around that by declaring the model type of the layout dynamic, i.e. `@model dynamic`

That should do the trick. The actual templates don't need to be altered.

Comment: Hi, thanks it works. But I read that it has some problem to with high load https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/180 May be the ViewBag is better solution...

Comment: The ViewBag seems like a pretty poor solution to me, because you don't have the benefits of a strong-typed model in the view. I actually saw that issue you linked to and disregarded it, but now that you mention it again, we _may_ have the same issue in our project. Our application only sends a couple hundred emails per day tops, but it does run out of memory within a couple weeks. I suspected some COM calls, but couldn't nail it down with load tests. Maybe I was looking in the wrong place. I should probaly run different load tests.